Nonzero voltage between identical electrodes in water
I placed two identical electrodes inside a recipient filled with tap water and measured a nonzero voltage with a DC component that started around - 30 mV and continued changing until reaching -40 mV. The measurement was done using a high precision digital multimeter (DC) and repeated with an oscilloscope and the result was the same.
I also noticed that these values varied after plugging out and in again the probes.
Given that the electrodes are identical and I had the same solution (water), I wasn't expecting any electrochemical reactions to occur and no voltage between the electrodes. So, I'm puzzled about the result.
I know about concentration cells but since I have the same solution I don't expect a difference in cencentration to be the source of this voltage.
Can anyone explain or give hints on the origin of this voltage? And also about the reason for the voltage decreasing?

Consider that the observed nonzero voltage may not have the electrochemical origin. You have not provided electrode material. Using water as electroly does not help either. the mest if you have used the solution of a salt of the same metal from which electrodes are made of.  Uneven establishment of equilibrium by each electrode due differences in surface quality may play a role to.

@Poutnik, I don't have dedicated electrodes. I'm actually using the (pointy) test leads that typically come with the digital multimeter. Basically, I put the test leads inside of water (I tested tap and distilled water) and see a nonzero voltage.

Is there zero DC voltage in then open circuit ? As it is quite normal there are dozens of mV, due high input impedance, disbalance of input circuitry and induced voltage from electrostatic gradient. there is possibility there is not strong enough DC current to nullify the open voltage.

@Poutnik, Keeping the test leads outside of water without touching them (open circuit measurement) gives a random DC voltage with values oscillating between positive and negative and absolute values around tens to hundreds of µV.

The thing is, the whole system is in badly defined state and there can be uneven kinetic conditions. So any possible small DC voltages and their drifts are possible.

Have you observed a similar behavior with pure distilled water, or with a more concentrated ionic solution instead of tap water ?

@Maurice, I did the experiment with tap and pure distilled water and I observed the same behavior. The only difference is that the values were not the same. For e.g., at some point I would get -7 mV with tap water and 13 mV with distilled water. However, these fluctuations were random from what I could see. I wasn't able to establish any correlation between measuring tap or distilled water.

Well, you show you got pretty sensitive detector. And that electrodes and water aren't as perfect as you think.

If the electrodes are removed from the water and maintained in the air, how does the voltage change ? If you interchange the wires leading to the electrodes on the meter, will it change the voltage ?

We had in early 1980s in high school an old, vacuum tube based pH meter, that had so high input impedance that we had to stand still without move at least 1.5 m away. Otherwise the pH reading got wild. Sure, PVC based lab floor and static electricity did not help.

Does the voltage seem to settle after long time static arrangement? Or, does it wander all the time, back and force?  How does it change if electrodes switch their locations? If it does not converge to some value, or if it is arrangement dependent, then some external influences are in the place.

The difficulties of making reliable measurements and other artifacts due to static charges etc, have been mentioned in the comments. Aside from these, the primary electrochemical effect is that any uncontrolled electrode in a solution will develop a potential called a mixed potential (or corrosion potential). In this effect, a current (anodic) due to an oxidation reaction occurs simultaneously with a current (cathodic) due to a reduction reaction. These occur on the same electrode, possibly at different locations, and the opposite currents cancel, meaning zero current leaves the electrode.
Common reactions are oxidation of the metal to give metal ions in solution or a small amount of oxide, coupled with reduction of trace amounts of dissolved oxygen to water. The potential is somewhere between the Nernst (equilibrium) potentials and is determined by the kinetics of these reactions, e.g., the rate of diffusion or convection of oxygen to the surface. It is common for these potentials to drift and not be very reproducible because the surface conditions and concentrations in solution are not very reproducible.
These potentials need not be small when properly measured against a reference electrode (with a very high-impedance voltmeter, $>10^{13}~ \Omega$). However, in the measurement here the difference between two such electrodes is being (unreliably) measured, each of them with similar reactions but slightly different local conditions, so a potential difference of the order of tens of mV is not unexpected.
So the short answer is the electrodes are not identical, having different concentrations of impurities or oxygen near them, and their surfaces are not identical., e.g, different metallurgical states of the electroplated coating.

If I understand correctly, this would mean that this voltage is really there (due to electrodes not being truly identical) and is not an inaccuracy or artifact of my measuring device.

Yes. Artifacts might mean that you wouldn't get the same value as with a high impedance, shielded measurement, but there will generally be a real potential difference.
